# Image processing: where do you think the issue is originated from?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on a lane detection project. Figure 1 shows one of the frames of the dashboard recording.

[image: Figure 1]

I have taken the following steps:

1. Removed the noise.

[image: Figure 2]

2. Detected the edges using Canny Edge Detector.

[image: Figure 3]

3. Masked out the top half of the image.

[image: Figure 4]

4. Applied a close morpholody to make continuous lines.

[image: Figure 5]

5. Applied a skeleton morphology to get the thinnest lines.

[image: Figure 6]

6. Performed a Hough transform on binary mask to obtain Hough matrix.
7. Identified the peaks in Hough matrix.
8. Extracted lines from the binary mask using *houghlines* function.
9. Calculated the line and marker positions from the previous step.
10. Visualized the line ([165,1,28]) and marker ([255,157,11]) on Figure 1.

[image: Figure 7]

But, as it can be seen, the white dashed lanes on the RHS are not detected. Where do you think the issue is and do you have any suggestions to fix it? Thanks.

I have tried to threshold the image by creating a binary mask using the histogram of the image and obtained better results but that method required some parameter tuning, which I am trying to avoid as this code (eventually) will be tested on a continuous video instead of a single frame.

Comment: we can only guess without code. but most likely the short lines don't have enough points to pass some threshold applied to the HT's accumulator array.

Answer (score 0):

The [Matlab implementation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html) of houghlines accepts the arguments **'MinLength'** and **'FillGap'**.

### **'MinLength'**

By playing around (=decreasing) with the 'MinLength' Parameter you should be able to make houghlines() accept also the short line on the right side. As your Image looks quite clean, you can even try to reduce it to a very small value such that even the very small part in the lower right corner can be detected as a line.

### **'FillGap'**

Next increase 'FillGap' to allow larger gaps between two line sgments. This might help you, produce one single line, for both right segments.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Currently I am using 100 both for MinLength and FillGap. What numbers do you think I should try?

Comment: I have not tested your particular scenario. Just give a couple of different parameter pairs a go and verify whether the result improves or not.